# Use Eclipse PDT (or Mylyn) drilldown, without the clutter

Tags: eclipse, codeigniter, hide, clutter, code-view

I am becoming a frequent user of eclipse, and I like it. However I find myself wondering:

*Is there a way I can use eclipse drill-down and then hide everything in enclosing folders except the folder that I'm drilling into?* (kind of how Mylyn filters stuff, but without me having to build a context)

I would like to do this, because I am using CodeIgniter and WAMP, which have numerous system files sitting in the higher level folders, most of which I don't care about and yet they take up space near the top of my project view. Is it possible to avoid this?

Thanks,

Lemiant

**Edit:** Although the above method would be ideal, if it is not possible, then is there a way to manually choose to hide files and folders in the project view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show only a selected sub-tree in any of the "navigator" views by right-clicking an item and selecting "Go Into" from the context menu. Everything except the contents of the selected item will be hidden. You can then use the "go up" button on the view's toolbar to climb back up to the workspace root.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Is it possible to "go into" more than one file at the same time? (on the same directory level)

Comment: @lemiant, sorry, not to my knowledge.